# Disk management report wrong drive size

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

Hello Any insight with this would be appreciate.

About a year ago I replaced the 2 hard drives for my win7 os.  Both were 1tb -
first drive is the boot drive and the second was just for data - the boot drive
was having some sort of I/O issues so, I replaced both drive.  I replaced the
boot drive with a 1tb drive û and since the second drive was just a ôdataö drive
- I replaced the 1tb drive with a 3tb drive

after the new hardware installed, I started up the computer -- I was able to
clone the boot drive and win7 started up fine.

So now I wanted to format the second drive, but windows was telling me the the
size of the second disk was just 768gb - I then reboot, when to the BIOS and
that reported the drive as 3TB.

I then took out the 3tb drive and formatted on another win7 machine û creating a
GPT and it formatted the full 3tb

I then put that drive back in the first computer and window now sees a 3tb drive, tools like testdisk and reflect still see the size as 768gb, but will use the formatted size of drive, 3TB

It seems to be working OK -- I was able to write files to it and last time I
checked I was using more that 50% of the drive -- past the 768gb "hardware" size

What do I need to do to have win7 find the correct size of the drive?  Thanks

Comment: You need to boot Windows 7 in UEFI mode.  Only 64-bit versions of Windows 7 support UEFi.  reflect Only saw the partition it did due to not enabling UEFI before you booted into its environment

Comment: this issue is NOT with the boot drive  -- not sure if  MOBO can boot in UEFI mode

Comment: Take the drive back to the machine in question, delete all partitions on it, then using the machine in question partition the unallocated space